# My orders in customer panel

Tags: magento-2.1, orders, customer-account

Want to merge order view in my order
Mean that, when I click on my orders tab, see all orders with detail not just orders number and view icon.
how can I merge these two pages?

Comment: any screen shots?

Comment: my orders has a link named view order, that shows order items, i want to show all items exactly on my-orders tab